# What role does the brain play in some eye diseases such as myopia and astygmatism?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, brain

I wondered if the brain is partially responsible for some vision problems that are usually solely attributed to the eyes even if the primary dysfunction happens in the eye.

For instance,in eye diseases where their severity can be measured by direct examination of the eye,if two people have the same eye condition with the exact same severity(eye damage status) is there any possibility that one of the two can see better due to brain/vision (composition or/and processing) differences?

I have found some papers that study the relationship between incranial/brain volume and eye illnesses like [myopia](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-18669-0) but nothing directly related to my question besides a paper which I can't find now about vision contrast and grey matter thickness of certain parts of the brain.

Comment: Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Now that your question is in an acceptable state for the science stacks, I think it's actually more appropriate for the Psychology & Neuroscience site, so I'm migrating it there.

Comment: I think brain is able to adjust and compensate. I’ve had astigmatism for many years, one eye very bad so the other compensating. Later I discover I’ve also have keratoconus  . Wearing new special lenses restored my eyes more evenly. When I sometimes switch back to glasses I notice one eye taking over again, compensating. Older people need reading glasses for the reason their brain is less responsive I was told by eye doctor.